# React API Data Loading Slow

Tags: reactjs, .net-core

I have a react front-end with .NET back-end with EF using the Azure database. For some reason, the pages load really slow and I am not really sure why... On the video, you will see exactly what I mean with the main page as an example. Here is also the function of the main page, with the api request, as you can see the console.log("GETTING DATA FROM SERVER") is loaded with page refresh, while the response is loaded in a few seconds, so I am really without a clue here...

I also thought that it could be the constant communication with the database, however, I tried to store a local list of products directly in the api and get the data from there, but that didn't change anything...

UPDATE:
It's probably due to the fact that each entity has 4 images set in the database.

```
        public void CreateProduct(Product p)
        {
            using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                if (p.MainImageFile != null)
                {
                    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        p.MainImageFile.CopyTo(stream);
                        p.MainImageData = stream.ToArray();
                    }
                }

                if (p.AdditionalImageFiles.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var file in p.AdditionalImageFiles)
                    {
                        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            file.CopyTo(stream);
                            p.AdditionalImages.Add(stream.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                }

                context.Products.Add(p);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

UPDATE x2: I found a solution, which would be to reduce the image data size. Here is how I did it:

```
public void CreateProduct(Product p)
{
    using (ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        if (p.MainImageFile != null)
        {
            p.MainImageData = ResizeImage(p.MainImageFile);
        }

        if (p.AdditionalImageFiles.Any())
        {
            foreach (var file in p.AdditionalImageFiles)
            {
                var resizedImage = ResizeImage(file);
                p.AdditionalImages.Add(resizedImage);
            }
        }

        context.Products.Add(p);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

private byte[] ResizeImage(IFormFile imageFile)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        imageFile.CopyTo(stream);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // Reset stream position to the beginning
        var image = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);

        // Determine the scale factor while maintaining aspect ratio
        int maxWidth = 1080; // Or any other dimension
        double scale = Math.Min((double)maxWidth / image.Width, 1); // Ensure scale is not more than 1
        var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * scale);
        var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * scale);

        using (var resizedImage = image.Resize(new SKImageInfo(newWidth, newHeight), SKFilterQuality.High))
        {
            if (resizedImage == null) return null; // Resizing failed, handle accordingly

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var skImage = SKImage.FromBitmap(resizedImage))
                using (var data = skImage.Encode(SKEncodedImageFormat.Png, 75)) // Adjust quality as needed
                {
                    data.SaveTo(ms);
                    return ms.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the database directly and running the command that pulls the data you are trying to get and see if it also hangs there?  If it doesn't then its your front end hanging rendering or a loop that isn't efficient most likely.  Also, how much data are you pooling?  Perhaps you could paginate the data to pull it in chunks so that the first chunk loads quickly to the screen and keeps adding more pages of data hopefully before the user can scroll to them.

Comment: I haven't really tried that, however in the swagger, the api request take approximately the same time to load as it does in react. So, it should be a problem in the backend, or just the huge amount of data I am pulling. There are only 18 entities, however, each has 4 pictures stored as an imageData, so my guess is that's what's causing the slow render time.

Comment: That is possible but 18 seems very low to hang it unless the images are more than a few Kb, then it would make sense. Is it possible you are using the original full size images and just displaying them smaller to look like thumb nails?  If that is the case, you can make smaller images the exact size you need and perhaps in a compressed file format (JPG vs PNG) so that they can render more quickly.  At the very least this test will give you more insight into the issue.

Comment: Is it possible to give me an example of what you mean exactly? I have updated the post with my code for storing the images.

Comment: I work in other languages unfortunately, however,  did you get a chance to look at the file sizes of the graphics to see if they were not actually thumbnails but full size files attempting to display into a smaller dimensions.  If the graphic is 1MB or bigger, its probably the original image and not a thumb nail version.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem, I managed to fix it, so thank you :)

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear that got you on the right track.